# filtered rows in navigable table

Tags: javascript, html

**UPDATE:**
I finally found a solution (with a while loop, in code below) but there is a problem: when I navigate search results (so elements which are not hidden), after navigating a bit in filtered results, the navigation stops working and I get a "TypeError: rows[selectedRow] is undefined"

```js
if(selectedRow >= rows.length){
                selectedRow = 0;
            } else if(selectedRow < 0){
                selectedRow = rows.length-1;
            }
```

This part works for the full list but not in the filtered list. I think the while loop is causing this. How can I fix this please ?

Navigation:

```js
var rows = document.getElementById("pokemons-list").children[1].children;
        var selectedRow = 0;
        
        document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
    
            //Clear out old row's color
            rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";

            //Calculate new row
            if(e.keyCode == 38){
                if(rows[selectedRow].style.display == "none"){
                while(rows[selectedRow].style.display == "none"){
                selectedRow--;
                }
                }else {
                    selectedRow--;
                }
            } else if(e.keyCode == 40){
                if(rows[selectedRow].style.display == "none"){
                while(rows[selectedRow].style.display == "none"){
                selectedRow++;
                }
                }else {
                    selectedRow++;
                }
            } else if(e.keyCode == 13){
                Pokemon_ID = selectedRow + 1;
                document.getElementById("id-input").value = Pokemon_ID;
                document.getElementById("id-input").click();
            }
            if(selectedRow >= rows.length){
                selectedRow = 0;
            } else if(selectedRow < 0){
                selectedRow = rows.length-1;
            }
            
            //Set new row's color
            rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";

        
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your filter function hides rows that don't match the string that you've entered. The hiding is implemented by setting the *display* property to "none".

When you navigate, can't you ignore table rows that have their display property set to "none"?

**Update:** You can check the value of `rows[selectedRow].style.display` before performing `rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue"`. If the value is `"none"`, repeat the change that you made to `selectedRow` within the function (whether it was an increment or a decrement).

**Update 2:** Consider the block of code below:

```
while(rows[selectedRow].style.display == "none"){
    selectedRow++;
}
```

If the value of `selectedRow` on entering the while loop is `0` and `rows[0].style.display` has the value `"none"` then the body of the loop changes the value of `selectedRow` to -1. The control will immediately go back to the loop guard and it'll try to check the value of
`rows[-1].style.display`. This is something you want to avoid, so why don't you try checking `selectedRow` after every line where you change it? A quick solution would involve changing the loop-bodies of your while loops:

```
while(rows[selectedRow].style.display == "none"){
    selectedRow++;
    if(selectedRow >= rows.length){
        selectedRow = 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
while(rows[selectedRow].style.display == "none"){
    selectedRow--;
    if(selectedRow < 0){
        selectedRow = rows.length-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works for you, consider upvoting or accepting the answer?

Comment: I said "this is what I'm trying to do but I can't find how to do this". I also need to take in count the "real" row number because when I press enter a value is sent by Ajax to a php file @Kartik Sabharwal

Comment: From what I understand, my update keeps the value of `selectedRow` consistent with the "real" row number.

Comment: thank you I found a solution thanks to you but now I face another problem (everything is in my update). Can you help me to fix this to get my search menu working please ?